# Jar file in an Android Studio project with multiple modules

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a single Android Studio project with 4 modules:

- two app modules;
- one Android library module;
- a fourth module `common` shared among the two app modules.

All the modules depend on a jar file developed by other people.

If I add the jar file in the `libs`folder of each submodule (app, library, `common`) everything is fine.

If I add a fifth module to the project as `Import .JAR or .AAR package module` and put a dependency on it in each submodule, no module finds the classes in the jar file.

If I look at the `build.gradle` commands for one of the two apps, I read this:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':library.myproject.com')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.2.0'
    compile project(':CommonClasses')
    compile project(':servicesJar')
}
```

The dependencies on `:library.myproject.com` and `:CommonClasses` are ok. The dependency on the jar file `:servicesJar` is not.

The `build.gradle` file for the jar is:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('Server.jar'))
```

What might be the cause?

Comment: No, I did not. I was only able to add a single jar file in a /libs folder and add it as a dependency to each submodule, even if AS tried to prevent me from doing that.